# List get distorted on scrolling

Tags: android

I am using custom ListView and when i scroll my list the image field of each listitem get replaced by some other image of some other listitem.

Can you please tell me some property of listview to prevent this.

Actually when we scroll the list the items those are not visible will perhaps
needs to  be populated again by list adapter each time during scroll.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please put your source codes. Then maybe we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using lazy load mechanism in this???

If yes, then before the actual image is fetched from the url, you need to set a stock image to the image view of your list item.

If not then the convertView can populate the older bitmap or drawble set to the image view of any other image view.

Answer (score 0):

Check this article on the Android Developers blog, it gives you a good insight on how to implement this. Additionally to this article, I would cache the images in WeakReferences and files to avoid multiple downloads of the same item...

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html